# What is the default File System in NetBSD? What are it's benefits and shortcommings?

Tags: filesystems, netbsd

I spent some time looking through the documentation, but honestly, I have not
found any good answer.

I understand NetBSD supports many FS types as USER SPACE, but I would like to know what is the default FS created by the installer, and the one which I could boot from.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  What platform?  Local disk?

A generic answer would be **FFSv2**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/721951)

Comment: try reading the second sentence fixer1234

Comment: I did read the whole post (it's pretty brief).  The second sentence isn't really an answer within the site's intention without clarification and expansion.  You say it depends, and then toss out FFSv2 with no explanation of where or how it fits in the "depends".  So the answer doesn't really answer or explain anything, which is what landed it in the review queue and likely why it attracted a downvote.  Can you expand the post?